# How to determine if two elements from a list appear consecutively in a string? Python

Tags: python-3.x, insert

I am trying to solve a problem that can be modelled most simply as follows.

I have a large collection of letter sequences. The letters come from two lists: (1) member list (2) non-member list. The sequences are of different compositions and lengths (e.g. AQFG, CCPFAKXZ, HBODCSL, etc.). My goal is to insert the number '1' into these sequences when any 'member' is followed by any two 'non-members':

```
Rule 1: Insert '1' after the first member letter that is followed 
by 2 or more non-members letters.
Rule 2: Insert not more than one '1' per sequence.

The 'Members': A, B, C, D
'Non-members': E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z
```

In other words, once a member letter is followed by 2 non-member letters, insert a '1'. In total, only one '1' is inserted per sequence. Examples of what I am trying to achieve are this:

```
AQFG        --->   A1QFG
CCPFAKXZ    --->   CC1PFAKXZ
BDDCCA      --->   BDDCCA1
HBODCSL     --->   HBODC1SL
ABFCC       --->   ABFCC
ACKTBB      --->   AC1KTBB # there is no '1' to be inserted after BB
```

I assume the code will be something like this:

```
members = ['A','B','C','D']
non_members = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N',
'O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
strings = ['AQFG', 'CCPFAKXZ', 'BDDCCA', 'HBODCSL', 'ABFCC']

for i in members:
    if i in strings:
        if member is followed by 2 non-members: # Struggling here
            i.insert(index_member, '1')            
        return i
return ''
```

**EDIT**

I have found that one solution could be to generate a list of all permutations of two 'non-member' items using `itertools.permutations(non_members, 2)`, and then test for their presence in the string.

But is there a more elegant solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating all permutations is going to explode the number of things you are checking. you need to change how you are iterating something like:

```
members = ...
non_members = ...
s = 'AQFG'
out = ""
look = 2
for i in range(len(s)-look):
    out += s[i]
    if (s[i] in members) & \
       (s[i+1] in non_members) & \
       (s[i+2] in non_members):
           out += '1' + s[i+1:]
           break
```

This way you only need to go through the target string once, and you don't need to generate permutations, this method could be extended to look ahead many more than your method.

Comment: Thanks! Very smart. However, when I implement this I get: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'` on this line `out.append(s[-2:])`. How to bypass that?

Comment: @twhale oops list has .append, string doesn't; replace all the append's with += ex: out += s[i] and out += s[-2:]

Comment: That gives this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'str'` on this line: `if s[i] in members & s[i+1] in non_members & s[i+2] in non_members:`. Am I making a mistake?

Comment: @twhale oh, you need parenthesis ()  here, i assumed it would work without.

Comment: Almost there ;-) This gives: `TypeError: must be str, not list` on line: `out += s[-look:]`

Comment: @twhale its not clear which is a list and why, in my code fragment, both out and s are strings, if you just set s= strings, this isn't correct, s = strings[0] would work

Comment: There is still one problem. This solution can add two '1's, for example, 'HBODCSL' becomes: 'HB1ODC1SL' instead of 'HB1ODCSL' as required per Rule 2. How to solved that in this approach?

Comment: @twhale I didn't catch that requirement, but it is a simple fix, the remaining error (still need to append the last two characters if we never insert anything) i will leave for you to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I believe can be done via regex also.

```
  s = 'AQFG'
  x = re.sub(r'([ABCD])([EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])',r'\g<1>1\2',s)
  print(x)
```

This will print A1QFG

Comment: Thanks. However, this can add two '1's, for example, `'HBODCSL'` becomes: `'HB1ODC1SL'` instead of `'HB1ODCSL'`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I missed that. re.sub can take an optional count parameter that can stop after the given number of replacements are made.

```
s = 'HBODCSL'
x = re.sub(r'([ABCD]+)([EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])',r'\g<1>1\2',s,count=1)
print(x)
```

This will print HB1ODCSL

Comment: Yes. I changed the pattern from my previous answer.